# Qt debug with release

Tags: qt

I am trying to debug a program I made with Qt 4.7.3 in Release mode.  I would like to debug into this program.  Is there a way to build the Qt DLL libraries in release with debug info?

I'm on Windows using Visual Studios 2008.

Comment: Your question is not very logic - if you want to debug, use debug mode. In release mode, you cannot debug, or else it would also be a called debug mode. Could you clarify what you are trying to do?

Comment: I want to build Qt in release with debug info, so if I get crash reports from users I can follow the stack trace into the Qt libraries.

Comment: Then why don't you ship a debug build to your users? Performance issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate debug symbols for your release build of Qt on windows...

1. Add the flag "-Zi" to QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE in your qmake.conf.
2. Add the flag "/DEBUG" to QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE in your qmake.conf (you'll probably also want "/OPT:REF" and "/OPT:icf")

For a VC2008 build you would add this to Qt\mkspecs\win32-msvc2008\qmake.conf
Then configure and rebuild.

More details of the various qmake options available here:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html