# Qt: no map/pdb files generated for windows release builds

Tags: qt

My Qt 4.7.4 project file doesn't generate map/pdb files under windows release builds. thus, postmortem debugging is impossible.

Any flag to change that?

Comment: Are you using qmake to build the project or "just" Visual Studio"?

Comment: using Qmake/nmake from command line.

Comment: How about these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993061/build-qt-in-release-with-debug-info-mode http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238146/qt-debug-with-release

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adding the following to the .pro file:

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE+=/MAP
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE += /Zi
QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE +=/debug /opt:ref
```

Comment: Strange, this only worked for me if I set these as environment variables, but the .pro ignored them completely

Comment: you have to press "run qmake" in "build" menu for qtcreator to process the changes in .pro file

Comment: You may need to add  `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += -Oy-` or `QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE += -Oy-` (Qt 5)