# HowTo build Qt5 with correctly distributed release pdb files

Tags: build, qt5, release, pdb, vc90

I'd like to build Qt5 from sources with PDB files in **debug** and **release** mode, but I faced with two problems:

1. no release PDB files generated ([here](https://qt-project.org/faq/answer/how_to_build_pdb_for_release_version_of_qt) is the solution),
2. qt build system didn't deploy release PDB files to given `prefix` build folder as it does for the debug version after `nmake.exe install`.

Here is example:

```
> configure -confirm-license -debug-and-release -opensource -shared -platform win32-msvc2008 -prefix x86 -mp -no-opengl -nomake examples
> nmake.exe
> nmake.exe install
```

After building finished I had `qtbase\bin\x86\x86\bin` folder with **DLL**s, **LIB**s and only **debug PDB** files, except **release PDB** files. Qt build scripts didn't make a copy of release PDB files, as it does for debug PDB files. Release PDB files created, and located in there modules.

**Did any one know how to fix this?**

PS: As my own solution, I thought to copy all *.pdb files from each module folder, but I think that this case is the worst, and first I'll try to find more *human* solution.

PSS: Qt4 didn't have such behavior, and we don't have problems.

P3S: Here is Qt [similar bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-28915).

Thanks,
best regards!

---

Environment:

> **Version**: Qt 5.4.1
>
> **System**: Win 8.1
>
> **Toolset**: MSVS2008 (vc9)

---

Usefull links:

1. [qmake Variable Reference](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html)
2. [How to create .pdb files also for Release version of Qt library](https://blog.inventic.eu/2014/08/how-to-create-pdb-files-also-for-release-version-of-qt-library/)
3. [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234337/qt-no-map-pdb-files-generated-for-windows-release-builds)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved with `-force-debug-info` damn option...

Answer (score 1):

[Qt.io - release with pdb](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_project_org_faq#How_can_I_build_executables.2Flibraries_in_both_release_and_debug_mode_on_Windows.3F)

append (not insert at file beginning):

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE    = -O2 -MD -zi
QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE    = /INCREMENTAL:NO /DEBUG
```

into qmake.conf, then you will get release pdbs